# How to fetch only selected fields in book search results?

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am using this code to fetch results from the Amazon API:

```java
//ItemSearch  where the request is stored as a dictionary.
var searchItem = new Dictionary<string, string>();
searchItem["Service"] = "AWSECommerceService";
searchItem["Version"] = AwsVersion;
searchItem["Operation"] = "ItemSearch";
searchItem["ResponseGroup"] = "ItemAttributes,Images";
searchItem["AssociateTag"] = "Books";
searchItem["SearchIndex"] = "Books";
searchItem["Condition"] = "All";
searchItem["ItemPage"] = itemPage;
searchItem["Keywords"] = searchText;

string searchDetailsRequestUrl = detailSearchSingedRequest.GetCompleteUrl(searchItem);
```

I need the book image, title, author, ISBN, and ISBN-13 only. How can I do this?

I have tried by putting `searchItem["ResponseGroup"] = "Medium"` but I got a larger XML response than with `ItemAttributes,Images`.

Comment: How slow is your item search? I don't believe you have much choice as the reponse groups are pre-defined by amazon and pretty large..

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_ResponseGroupsList.html

Comment: The itemsearch takes generally 4-6 seconds. I need to reduce this time. Is there any other way so that I can optimize the search ?

Answer (score 0):

Specify `ResponseGroup` to only certain items you want to retrieve will reduce your page load.